# How to concatenate strings using + operator

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

Why one is allowed while another produce error. Anyone who can explain.

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s3 = "Why";
    string s11 = "hello" + " , " + s3;  // It gives error
    string s11 =  s3 + " , " +"hello" ; // This works fine.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due the operator precedence, the line

```
string s11 = "hello" + " , " + s3;
```

is processed as

```
string s11 = ("hello" + " , " ) + s3;
```

The sub-expression `"hello" + " , "` is not legal.
The first term is of type `char const [6]` (an array of 6 `char const`) and the second term is of type `char const [4]` (an array of 4 `char const`).

There is no `+` operator between the two. That's why it's a compiler error.

---

The second line

```
string s11 =  s3 + " , " + "hello"
```

is processed as

```
string s11 =  (s3 + " , ") + "hello"
```

The sub-expression `s3 + " , "` is valid since there is an overload of the `operator+` that supports that operation. The sub-expression evaluates to a `std::string`. Hence, the subsequent `+ "hello"` is also a supported operation.

Answer (score 1):

`"hello"` is a string literal and its type is array of characters (`char[6]`). The `operator+` is defined only for `std::string`. You can use the udl `s` to make it `std::string`:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    std::string s3 = "Why"s;
    std::string s11 = "hello"s + " , "s + s3;
    std::string s12 =  s3 + " , "s +"hello";
}
```

Comment: oh great , it's working . Can you explain what's this udl(s) which you have mentinoed.

Comment: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/user-defined-literals-part-i/ , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal